# via actions add a component to a another component with ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js

I am currently learning Ember and I have come across a problem that I would like to solve.

I have a component that presents X amounts of buttons that are linked to actions on the component.

When one of these buttons are pressed the proper action should execute and in executing it should add a newly instantiated component to another component.

I realize that the proper way would not be to let component X know about component Y, but what does the proper solution look like?

Comment: It would be great if you could reproduce your problem in http://ember-twiddle.com/ and include some code in your post as well. I don't quite understand what is component X and what is component Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by daisy chaining an action from the source component to the destination component(the one I wanted to handle the action).

Component JavaScript:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    elementSelected: function(){
      this.sendAction('elementSelected', this.model);
    }
  }
});
```

Defining an action is not strictly required, it could be any code in javascript that actually calls sendAction. It is the sendAction that exposes an event to the world outside of the component.

Component template:

```
<div {{action 'elementSelected'}}>
</div>
```

Any subsequent component in the chain needs to bind the action to a local action. The implementation of that action is almost the same as the first component (note that we now pass whatever object/s from the original action through).

The Binding:

```
{{component-some-component type="text" elementSelected="elementSelected"}}
```

The Implementation:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    elementSelected: function(model){
      this.sendAction('elementSelected', model);
    }
  }
});
```

This solution really still leaves some issues:
1) Every component in the chain needs to know the action explicitly.
2) The verbosity re-sending the action at each level.

Sadly this has a lot to do with how actions currently bubble in Ember 2.3<.

> By default, the {{action}} helper triggers a method on the template's
>   controller, as illustrated above.
>
> If the controller does not implement a method with the same name as
>   the action in its actions object, the action will be sent to the
>   router, where the currently active leaf route will be given a chance
>   to handle the action.

Source: https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/actions/
(this particular link is for 1.10, but this is still valid in 2.3)

As stated above, actions do not bubble through the component hierarchy, so what my verbose daisy-chain solution actually does is to explicitly bubble a specific event through the component hierarchy.

This might also be solved by a service or a helper class, but in my opinion component actions exposed to the outside world should bubble through the component chain before they land in the route.